# write a function to delete texts between html tag (style, script) from a column of DataTable in C#

Tags: html, c#-4.0

I have a table column in my DB where the whole HTML page-source-view is dumped and I need to clean it and extract to EXCEL file (extraction code is implimented in the project). I need to clean the specific DataTable column. the process which I want to follow is 
 
first
`Get the DB data in DataTable`
then
`Apply deletion of data inside “style” & “script” tag on the particular column of DataTable & Apply html tag cleaning logic to that column`
then
`Add the clean column data to the DataTable`
& finally
`Export to Excel with the help of DataTable object`
which is implemented.
So I thought to delete the content inside the (style, script) tags first then to delete the other tags. 
I wrote a snipet to delete the HTML tags,  which is:

```
    var output = new StringBuilder();
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                //but this code only accepts the html file  
                //how to provide a data from a DataColumn?
                doc.Load(htmlfilepath);
                foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*"))
                {
                    output.Append(node.InnerText.ToString() + "\n");
                    text1 = output.ToString();
                }
```

But before deleting the tags I need to delete the unwanted data inside the "style" and "script" tag as it will be easier to get the valuable data.

Please do help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in SQL? Maybe you should get data from DB, use scripting language (for example PHP) and save data to database if needed?

Comment: How Can I do it on the front end side with the DataTable object in C#?